# Swift 3 How to programmatically link an image to a button

Tags: ios, swift3

[My menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnYwo.png)

Above is what my menu bar/navigation drawer looks like. I use this in my swift file to show the logo as the navigation title ONLY when the menu bar is open, which works:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.init(image:UIImage(named:"MenuBarTransparent"))
```

However, I can not figure out how to (or even find out if it's possible) make the image that's created each time the menu bar is opened, link to one of the menu buttons in the list below it. Specifically, I have the "Discover The Bash" button linking to a certain URL, I want the image that's created to do the same. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that. 
One is to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to this image view.
And second, which is better, to replace `UIImageView` in `titleView` with `UIButton`, which will trigger the same function as "Discover The Bash" button.